# Extract substring match from agrep

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance, agrep

My Goal is to identify whether a given `text` has a `target` string in it, but i want to allow for typos / small derivations and extract the substring that "caused" the match (to use it for further text analysis).

**Example:**

```
target <- "target string"
text <- "the target strlng: Butter. this text i dont want to extract."
```

**Desired Output:**

I would like to have `target strlng` as the Output, since ist very Close to the target (levenshtein distance of 1). And next i want to use `target strlng` to extract the word `Butter` (This part i have covered, i just add it to have a detailed spec).

**What i tried:**

Using adist did not work, since it compares two strings, not substrings.

Next i took a look at `agrep` which seems very Close. I can have the Output, that my target was found, but not the `substring` that "caused" the match.

I tried with `value = TRUE` but it seems to work on Array Level. I think It is not possible for me to Switch to Array type, because i can not split by spaces (my target string might have spaces,...).

```
agrep(
  pattern = target, 
  x = text,
  value = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aregexec`, it's similar to the use of `regexpr/regmatches` (or `gregexpr`) for exact matches extraction.

```
m <- aregexec('string', 'text strlng wrong')
regmatches('text strlng wrong', m)
#[[1]]
#[1] "strlng"
```

This can be wrapped in a function that uses the arguments of both `aregexec` and `regmatches`. Note that in the latter case, the function argument `invert` comes *after* the dots argument `...` so it must be a named argument.

```
aregextract <- function(pattern, text, ..., invert = FALSE){
  m <- aregexec(pattern, text, ...)
  regmatches(text, m, invert = invert)
}

aregextract(target, text)
#[[1]]
#[1] "target strlng"

aregextract(target, text, invert = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "the "                                       
#[2] ": Butter. this text i dont want to extract."
```